# How to detect what line you are on in console?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, terminal, windows-console

I'd like to use the value for which line the user is currently on in the console (see picture to see what terminal I'm on about) [Terminal/Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnxLx.png)

For this picture, I would want this command to output the integer '1' as it is on the first line of the console

for the second picture  [Second Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHZqs.png), i would want this command to output the integer '7' as the flashing white dash is on the seventh row of the console/terminal

Any ideas on how to obtain this value?

(I'm using Python 3.6)

Comment: The current cursor position is a property of the screen buffer, which can be queried via [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo).